# Can i add a JS Link to a list view in modern interface

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, jslink, modern-experience

I have the following JS link , which i have added to classic interface inside our sharepoint on-premises 2013:-

```
(function () {

      function registerRenderer() {
        var ctxForm = {};
        ctxForm.Templates = {};

        ctxForm.Templates = {
            Fields : {
                'LinkTitle': { //------ Change Hyperlink of LinkTitle
                    View : function (ctx) {
                        alert("123");
                        if(ctx.CurrentItem.SiteCreated != null && ctx.CurrentItem.SiteCreated === 'Yes'){
                        var url = String.format('{0}{1}', "/sites/projectmanagement/", ctx.CurrentItem.ID);
                        return String.format('<a href="{0}" onclick="EditItem2(event, \'{0}\');return false;">{1}</a>', url, ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var url = String.format('{0}{1}', "/Lists/projects/DispForm.aspx?ID=", ctx.CurrentItem.ID);
                        return String.format('<a href="{0}" onclick="EditItem2(event, \'{0}\');return false;">{1}</a>', url, ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        };
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
    }
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');


})();
```

then i reference it as follow inside the list view:-

[image]

now the JS link will modify the item url base on a custom column value. When i migrated the site to sharepoint online, the JSLINK will work perfectly on classic interface, but if i switch to modern interface the JSLINK will not have any effect.
so can anyone advice if i can use my JSLINK to have effect on modern interfaces in sharepoint online? if the answer is No, then what are the approaches i can follow to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SharePoint Online modern interface list view, the JSLINK will not works.

We can use the column formatting to achieve your requirement, the following official document for your reference.

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: looks like lot of steps, just to have list view formats ... second question, who will be able to add/modify column formatting?  as i have noted that users with Read-Only permissions were able to add their own custom column formatting...

Comment: Unfortunately, if the users only have  Read-Only permissions, they can't add their own custom column formatting.

Comment: so does contributor users have permission to add custom column formatting?.. if they can, then if i (as a sharepoint admin) add a custom column formatting, then any contributor user will be able to modify it?? this will be an issue..

Answer (score 0):

JSLink does not works on modern interface, it is default disabled. Microsoft is advising to migrate your JSLinks to SharePoint Framework Field Customizers/SharePoint Framework Extensions.

Microsoft has also published the article on their official documentation site. You may check here:

[Migrating JSLink customizations to SharePoint Framework Field Customizers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-jslink-to-spfx-extensions)

[Migrating from JSLink to SharePoint Framework Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-from-jslink-to-spfx-extensions)

Going ahead all SharePoint Online customizations will be more SharePoint Framework centric.

***An extract from above 1st article:***

> One of the main benefits of migrating old-school JSLink customizations
>   to the SharePoint Framework is that it is the only supported technique
>   that you have on modern sites for customizing the UI of "modern" lists
>   and libraries. In fact, the "modern" lists and libraries, because of
>   their rendering infrastructure and because of the no-script flag
>   enabled on the "modern" sites, can't rely on old-school JSLink
>   customizations. Thus, if you really want to extend the "modern" UI,
>   you need to upgrade to the SharePoint Framework.